PC Game where you are transported into a fantasy video game, and it's made clear that you're not the hero
The art style was 2D pixel art, and not terribly sophisticated. It was fairly colorful and bright as I recall it. The basic story is that you get transported into a video game as the hero, but the wizard who has transported you in is blunt (and a bit insulting) about how you're not really the hero. I don't remember if it was an accident, or something where he got a sadistic glee out of the predicament, but you're basically told that you, lacking any actual heroic skills, would die soon. Except, of course, contrary to the narrative, you turn out to be as able as any video game character. I have a vague memory of the first weapon being a small dagger, and the first enemy something like a goblin. After you survive the first encounter, and gain your first bits of gear, the wizard is still dismissive of how long you will survive and continues insulting you. I don't think I played for terribly long. It might have been 5+ years ago that I played it, and I think it was a an independent game, not from a major publisher. I vaguely remember it being a decently well-known one at the time.
The title might have been something like Not the Hero or Not So Epic. I remember that it was riffing on you not really being the hero of the narrative.
The gameplay was sidescrolling platforming/action, like Castlevania. The camera might have focused on a "scene/room" at a time rather than continuously centering the player, but I'm less certain on that.
Suggestions from the comments that I have ruled out

You Are Not the Hero
NOT A HERO
Companions of Xanth


Do you remember anything about the gameplay? Sidescrolling? Top down? Action/turn-based/automatic?

it's not this one is it? https://store.steampowered.com/app/268970/You_Are_Not_The_Hero/

It was sidescrolling, like Castlevania. Which means it probably was not You Are Not the Hero.

https://store.steampowered.com/app/274270/NOT_A_HERO/?

@valorum; More fantasy based, I think, medieval magic and monsters.

Could it be 1993's 'Companions of Xanth', based on Piers Anthony's novel series? I've never played the game, but have read the Xanth novel based on the game, which has a plot similar to what you describe.

Ah, no, that game is point and click adventure.

Possibly Unepic (2011) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unepic ?

also, see here (warning: tvtropes): https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TheUnchosenOne/VideoGames

@jo1storm: I didn't even see your other comment... sorry.

@FuzzyBoots just don't forget to mark your answer as correct. :)

I went ahead and scanned my Steam library for "hero" and "epic" for matching titles, and didn't have much luck. Remembering that, at one point, I also got a lot of games via Desura, and often didn't redeem my Steam keys for games that I'd gotten from there, I did a search in my Humble Bundle library, and came up with UnEpic. One install later, and I'm convinced it's the right one, and that I mixed up some details.

Unepic is a role-playing platformer game with Metroidvania elements and nonlinear gameplay, inspired by the 1987 MSX game The Maze of Galious. Players can use a number of melee and ranged weapons and armors as determined by their level and skill points assigned to an applicable type of equipment. Simple crafting for potions is also available in limited locations, and merchants are present throughout the game, believing the player is a possessed monster. "UnEpic Points" are awarded for completion of long and difficult challenges, and can be used to purchase powerful equipment such as laser guns, flamethrowers, and rocket launchers.

From the Steam page:

Daniel was just an average guy. He was a great videogame player, a big fan of sci-fi movies, and a novice RPG player. In the midst of an RPG, he was teleported to a castle. At first, Daniel believed that he was having a massive hallucination. Eager to keep playing within the RPG to create his own adventure, he decides to go along for te ride until his delirium comes to an end.
Once inside the castle, Daniel is inhabited by a mysterious shadow. This dark spirit can communicate with Daniel, but not control him. The shadow has a simple goal: to escape from the prison of Daniel's body. There's a catch, though-- the dark spirit can only escape if Daniel perishes.
Struggling against enemies in the castle, with the dark spirit attempting to murder him at every turn. Daniel finally discovers his goal: to kill Harnakon, the master of the castle, and free the Pure-Spirits who are trapped within. While the stage seems set for a typical role-playing adventure, Daniel will soon discover that everything is not what it seems...

Not matching, it's the demon possessing him, Zeratul, who mocks him. Poking around, it seems that Harnakon was the one who summoned him.
